# Calling on click listener multiple times for updating text views?

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

In my activity i am showing user a question and 3 options to choose from, these options are text-views.

On clicking the text-view On click listener is performed which updates the text-views according to the option selected.

Now user again after reading the question performs on click listener on options. But this is working only twice then it stops clicking and updating.

Debug is not working either i am beginner so i am confused.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if(id == R.id.optionA) {
        Answer =  optionA;
        LogAnswer = "a : " + optionA;
        Log.w(TAG, LogAnswer);
        conditions(questionnumber);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.optionB) {
        Answer = optionB;
        LogAnswer = "b : " + optionB;
        Log.w(TAG, LogAnswer);

         conditions(questionnumber);
    }

    else if (id == R.id.optionC) {
        Answer = optionC;
        LogAnswer = "c : " + optionC;
        Log.w(TAG, LogAnswer);
        conditions(questionnumber);

    }
   }
```

conditions method change text-views according to option.

```
 public void conditions(int i){

    if(Answer.equals(optionA) && i == 1 )
    {
        questionnumber = 2;
        MartialStatus = Single;
        GetQuestion(2);


    }
 else if(Answer.equals(optionB) && i == 1 )
    {
        questionnumber = 2;
        GetQuestion(2);


    }


   }
```

It may be that my text-view onclicklistener is calling same text-view listener which breaks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems like you hardcoded your question switching inside of `conditions` method. Rewrite it to by dynamic and you will probably solve it

Comment: I agree with @dniHze. Additionally, you should also share your ```setOnClickListener``` code. There may be a problem with that part.